# MySQL timediff function does not give proper output

Tags: mysql, sql

This function

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2020-06-17 12:15:00am','2020-06-17 01:15:00am')) as 'diff'
```

gives me the difference as

> 11 hours

while actually it should be

> 1 hour

. How do I fix this? Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: That's MySQL, not PHP.

Comment: Sorry. Was in a hurry... Thanks for rectifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't recognize `am` and `pm` by default, it parses times in 24-hour format. You need to use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) if you want to parse a custom datetime format.

Also, you need to put the later time first.

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE('2020-06-17 01:15:00am', '%Y-%m-%d %r'),
                     STR_TO_DATE('2020-06-17 12:15:00am', '%Y-%m-%d %r'))) as 'diff'
```